# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small, Using shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, plsql

I saw a lot of answers for the same query but didn't find any issue with my code. I am getting this error in declare block. p_pid is process id which is 4 digit long.Just for information I am using bash scripts to pass some parameters to sql blocks.

**PL/Sql Block**

```
      declare
          v_errorseq number := ${p_pid};
      begin
          log_table_pkg.set_stamp_num(v_errorseq);
```

**log_table_pkg**

```
    gv_stamp_num  number;
    gv_host_name  varchar2;
    gv_seq_num    varchar2;

    procedure set_stamp_num(p_stamp_num   number)
    is
    begin
    if p_stamp_num is null
    then
     raise_application_error(-20001,'Null stamp number.');
     end if;
     gv_stamp_num := p_stamp_num;
    end;
```

Comment: it's not construct-able, please provide the context where is the bash script that is passing !

Comment: I am calling the pl/sql script like this 
lf_execute_plsql -l $temp_log \
      -s "${v_plsql_string}" \(Some query)
      -p $C_PID \(process ID)

Comment: Its a whole production code of about 2 pages, so it's like impossible to paste it here.